# Gensim HDP topic model: How to train on multiple passes of corpus?

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

Gensim's HDP model for topic modeling (gensim.models.hdpmodel.HdpModel) has a constructor that takes an argument called `max_chunks`.

On the documentation, it says `max_chunks` is the number of chunks the model will go over, and if that is larger than the number of chunks in supplied corpus, the training will wrap around the corpus.

Since I was warned by INFO logs that the likelihood function has been decreasing, I figure I may need multiple passes on corpus to converge.

LDA model provides with the `passes` argument the functionality to train on corpus for multiple iterations. I have difficulty figuring out how `max_chunks` in HDP maps to `passes` in LDA.

For example, let say my corpus has 1000000 documents. what `max_chunks` needs to be exactly in order to train, say, 3 passes on my corpus.

Any suggestion? Many many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class gensim.models.hdpmodel.HdpModel(corpus, id2word, max_chunks=None, max_time=None, chunksize=256, kappa=1.0, tau=64.0, K=15, T=150, alpha=1, gamma=1, eta=0.01, scale=1.0, var_converge=0.0001, outputdir=None, random_state=None)`

I think if you have 1000000 documents then if you use the default chunksize of 256 you'll need to have max_chunks=100000/256*3 to force 3 passes.

I'm also getting the `WARNING : likelihood is decreasing!` message, and I think that my corpus is too small (608 short texts) and too uniform to find topics in.

Answer (score 2):

The `chunksize`, `passes` and also `update_every` options can be a bit confusing. What helped me was this [link](http://miningthedetails.com/blog/python/lda/GensimLDA/) and specifically the section `Chunksize, Passes, and Update_every`

So in your case, if you are doing [batch-LDA](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html) with `update_every` set to 0 and `chunksize` set to the number of documents, with `passes` set to 3 you should get three passes over the complete corpus.

In case of [online-LDA](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html), where `update_every` is set to 1, you could additionally use the `chunksize` to control the size of the mini-batches per pass.